# jquery to check when a someone starts typing in to a field

Tags: jquery

```
$('a#next').click(function() {
    var tags = $('input[name=tags]');

    if(tags.val()==''){

    tags.addClass('hightlight');  
    return false; 
    }else{
    tags.removeClass('hightlight');
    $('#formcont').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#next').hide('slow');
        return false;
    }
});
```

I would like the above code to fire the fadeIn as soon as somebody starts typing into the tags input. Can somebody tell me the correct way to do this or point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

EDIT

here is the code to do it:

```
$('input#tags').keypress(function() {

    $('#formcont').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#next').hide('slow');
});
```

The only problem I've found is that my cursor no longer shows up in the text box. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like the fade is moving your focus, hence the cursor no longer being there.  Try this

```
$('input#tags').keypress(function() {

    $('#formcont').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#next').hide('slow');
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the [focus event](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

```
  $('a#next').focus(function() {
      $('#formcont').fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

Comment: If he wants something to happen when they start typing, then this won't do what he needs.

Comment: but keypress will fire with every keypress not just the first

Answer (score 0):

`input#tags` is redundant and wasteful.

```
$('#tags').keypress(function() {

    $('#formcont').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#next').hide('slow');
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: unless you're using jquery specific selectors (eg. :not()) then saying "input" is wasteful is overkill. The programming cost of the css selector is negligible and is just looking for something to change to put a seperate answer.